# Object mapping fields

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I have an objects class A:

```
  public class A {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String mail;
    private String moreData;
    // ...
  }
```

class B:

```
  public class B {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String crc;
    // ...
  }
```

Can I use jackson to provide field mapping from object A to B copying correspond fields into target object.

I need from object

```
  A {
    Long id = 23L;
    String name = "name";
    String mail = "mail";
    String moreData = "moreData";
    // ...
  }
```

get as target object

```
  B {
    Long id = 23L;
    String name = "name";
    String crc = mull;
    // ...
  }
```

after object mapping processing...

Is it possible implement solution using *com.fasterxml.jackson* in simple way?

Comment: You can use BeanIO for example (http://www.beanio.org/2.0/docs/reference/index.html).

Comment: I can try it, but in my project is used faster xml, so I want use it for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.   Not withstanding a full understanding of why you want to do this, or that I think there might be more efficient ways than converting to JSON then back, but if you would like to use Jackson, here is what I would do:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
B b = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(a), B.class);
```

Hope this helps.  should do the job.    The key will be to tell Jackson to not fail on unknown properties so it drops those you are not sure of.